# Comparing two different pointers to elements of a linked list

Tags: pointers, linked-list, element

[image]

Anyone knows if there are there any method for comparing the two pointers, let's say there are two pointers `ptr1` and `ptr2`, as shown in the picture, how can i perform some operations similar `(ptr2 < ptr1)` to check whether a specific pointer passed another pointer, for example to check whether ptr2 passed ptr1 such that ptr2 is on the right side while ptr1 is on the left side. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your question language agnostic, or is it in the context of a specific programming language?

Comment: Any reason why you never seem to respond to comments?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the pointer values themselves will not tell you which node is before the other one in a linked list. For that you will need to step through your linked list.

You could have these pointers traverse the linked list in tandem. The one that reaches the end of the list first is necessarily the one that is coming *after* the other one.

In pseudo code (c-style):

```cpp
int compare(node* ptr1, node* ptr2) {
    if (ptr1 == ptr2) return 0;  // equal
    while (ptr1 != NULL && ptr2 != NULL) {
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        ptr2 = ptr2->next;
    }
    return ptr2 == NULL ? -1 : 1;
}
```

If the list is long, and the pointers are not far from each other, you can gain some time by also checking whether one of the traversing pointers becomes equal to an original pointer. Then you can also take your conclusions:

```cpp
int compare(node* ptr1, node* ptr2) {
    if (ptr1 == ptr2) return 0;  // equal
    cur1 = ptr1;
    cur2 = ptr2;
    while (true) {
        if (cur2 == NULL || cur1 == ptr2) return -1; // ptr1 before ptr2
        if (cur1 == NULL || cur2 == ptr1) return  1; // ptr2 before ptr1
        cur1 = cur1->next;
        cur2 = cur2->next;
    }
}
```

All this assumes that the given pointers are both pointing to members of the **same** linked list. With the above function you can now do:

```cpp
// ...
int res = compare(ptr1, ptr2);
if (res < 0) output("*ptr1 comes before *ptr2");
if (res > 0) output("*ptr1 comes after *ptr2");
if (res == 0) output("*ptr1 is the same as *ptr2");
```